Always render an intercepted route in a modal even if navigating to the url directly in next.js
I am using the Parellel routes and route Interception to create a user experience that opens a form (the /new route) in a modal for the user to create their new thing. The route is /posts/new.
However, when refreshing that route or going to it directly (ie. not a soft navigation or using the Link component, it renders the actual /posts/new page itself and I do not want this.
What I want is that whenever you get to /poosts/new I ALWAYS want this page to render in a modal, never on it's own.
Is this something I can do with just normal route behavior or do I need to resort to using query params?
